# iOS UIWebView trouble playing videos

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a bar code scanning application that uses UIWebView for bar codes that contain URL's. If the URL is for a youtube video, I am lucky if it works 1 in 20 times. On an iPhone 4S with iOS 6.0.1, if the video does play, I don't get sound. On an iPhone 5 with iOS 6.1.4, if I get video I get sound also.

I read that there may a problem with iOS 6 and playing full screen video and so I implemented UIMoviePlayerControllerDid{Enter/Exit}FullscreenNotification handlers and I prevent viewWillDisappear being passed to the super class when in full screen mode.

Here is the debug output for video without sound on iPhone 4:

```
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player: 1)
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
[MPCloudAssetDownloadController] Prioritization requested for media item ID: 0
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player: 1)
[MPAVController] Autoplay: _streamLikelyToKeepUp: 0 -> 1
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player: 1)
[MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
```

When there is no video or sound, I get the following after the 3rd "Enabling auto play":

```
Disabling autoplay for route change
Disabling autoplay
```

Comment: Sometime, I can't run mp3, mp4 file with UIWebview.